# routing an entire controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to route an entire controller with laravel 4 using this:

```
Route::controller('mycontroller', 'MyController');
```

When user comes to this url:

http://my.app/mycontroller/anyMethod

then `anyMethod` method in `MyController` should work.

It should work for all methods defined in that class.

Currently when i go to: my.app/mycontroller, it throws `NotFoundHttpException`

when i go to: my.app/mycontroller/aDefinedMethod, it throws `NotFoundHttpException` and says: Controller method not found.

What is wrong?

UPDATE: As i understand, Route::controller() is now restful in Laravel 4. Ok then, i don't want a restful controller and i don't want to rename my methods. So how should i setup a route to achieve this?

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: Curious why you don't want to rename the methods?

Answer (score 2):

You're defining it as a RESTful controller. my.app/mycontroller/index will correspond to a method called getIndex().

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your controller - the issue is probably you a not defining a 'restful' controller functions. [Route::controller() is now restful in Laravel 4 - See here for more info.](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

So therefore when you go to url

http://my.app/mycontroller/anyMethod

then it should be

`getAnyMethod()` in your `MyController`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here.  One is you need to prepend the action you are looking for to the method name.  So for example, your method name should read `getAnyMethod()` and it would respond to `mycontroller/any-method`.

Comment: Lifesaver! Omg, why Laravel requires hyphen? That should be optional!

Comment: Not sure exactly, but I believe it is so your URI would look cleaner.  `myapp.com/public/mycontroller/any-method` looks nicer than `myapp.com/public/mycontroller/anyMethod`

Comment: For sure it looks nicer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a RESTful controller, you should register all your controller's functions  with named routes like shown below, so that Laravel 4 can properly reflect to a particular method of a particular controller and execute it, when you enter the url in your browser.

```
Route::get('yourcontrollerslug', array('as' => 'your.route.name', 'uses' => 'YourController@someFunctionOne'));
Route::post('yourcontrollerotherslug', array('as' => 'your.route.othername', 'uses' => 'YourController@someFunctionTwo'));
```

In the [L4 documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing) it is reffered to mapping route names (and in result the particular routes) to controller actions.

```
// You may also specify route names for controller actions:

Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Maybe there actually are other ways to achieve what you want in a more convenient manner - but I am not aware of such :)

Hope this helps you out anyway.